# Errors when plotting large dataset from text file using pgfplot & tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, luatex

my PC crashed and after reinstalling LaTeX I'm faced with the following errors when trying to plot a large data set from a text file. I'm using LuaLaTeX. I can't seem to find out what is causing this error, but it appears only be at the end of the code, can anyone identify the problem? Thank you

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\sa@placebox ->\newpage \global \pdfpagewidth
=\wd \sa@box \global \pdfpageh...
l.47 \end{document}

! You can't use a prefix with `the character ='.
<to be read again>
=
l.47 \end{document}

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
\global
l.47 \end{document}

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again>
\global
l.47 \end{document}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.15}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
 y tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            fixed zerofill,
            precision=0,
        /tikz/.cd
    },
    %title={Displacement time-history},
    xlabel={Time [s]},
    ylabel={Displacement [mm]},
    xmin=0, xmax=35,
    ymin=-10, ymax=4,
    xtick={0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35},
    ytick={-10,-8,-6,-4,-2,0,2,4},
    legend pos=south east,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    xmajorgrids=true,
    grid style=solid,
    every axis plot/.append style={thin}
]

\addplot[
    color=black
    ]
    table{45M_S11_M1_U-Z1021.txt}
    ; 

    \legend{Displacement}    

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My text file is in the format:

```
DYNA-HIST   u-Z      1021   
0.0000000   0   
0.0020000   2.36066E-08 
0.0040000   3.0517E-07  
0.0060000   1.87772E-06 
0.0080000   7.65819E-06 
0.0100000   2.34945E-05 
0.0120000   5.77034E-05 
0.0140000   0.000117438 
0.0160000   0.000201915 
0.0180000   0.000295498 
0.0200000   0.000365356
```

Comment: The `standalone` class hasn't been updated to support the latest versions of LuaTeX, so you need to add `\RequirePackage{luatex85}` before `\documentclass`.